# Set application version in footer globally in layout view in asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, version

I want to include in the layout view of my ASP.NET MVC application the version.

I use this in index action to get the version:

```
    var version = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HomeController)).GetName().Version;
    ViewBag.Version = version + " / " + YlaGeneralUtilities.GetBuildDateTime(version);
```

Afterwards in the view i simply output Viewbag.Version.

I want the version to exist anywhere and not only to the homeController/Index action.

One workaround is to include the actual code above in the layout view:

```
@{
    var version = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HomeController)).GetName().Version;
    ViewBag.Version = version + " / " + YlaGeneralUtilities.GetBuildDateTime(version);
}
```

But i dont like the idea of having "logic" in the view..Is this the only way?

Comment: What about just having the version set in a configuration value somewhere?  (app.config, fishes.config etc)

Comment: Why you dont like keeping it in `layout.cshtml`? where you like to keep and how you want? I think layout option is ok

Comment: @Murali: I think also but what would happen if you needed something with more logic in the layout? I dont liek the idea of putting logic in the view..thats the only reason..

Comment: @Arran: I need to auto increment the version from my homecontroller.dll assembly version

Comment: I thought you want mvcapp.dll. why do you create a dll for each controller?

Comment: sorry, idont...figure of speach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative:

You could use a little "utility" controller in combination with jquery to populate the version value in your views asynchronously.  The controller would have a single Action: `GetVersion`.  This wouldn't take much code and should work cleanly across the site if you use an element in the layout.

Comment: nice idea, but one question: i put the element in layout and the script in section scripts. Thi will ensure that it will run at the end of page load?

Comment: This looks like the information you need to ensure loading order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347628/proper-place-to-load-jquery-in-mvc-layout-view